# Password problems with SqlConnection

Tags: c#, connection-string, sqlconnection

I create my connection string like this:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=MyPC\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=false;User Id=TestUser;password=TestPwd"
```

I create a SQL connection like this:

```
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

I then create my SqlBulkCopy object like this:

```
var bulkData = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity);
```

The problem is that I'm getting error 18456, Status 8 error message when the bulk copy tries to execute.  This error indicates a password mismatch.  Yet, I can log into the database with the exact credentials presented above.

So, I stepped through my program and noticed this:  The connection string, in debug, looks as it should, with the user ID and password.  However, when I hover my cursor over the bulk copy's `sqlConnection.ConnectionString`, it shows the entire connection string WITHOUT the password.  It only has the user!  For some reason, it appears that my password is not being used when I create the SQL Connection using the connection string that has the password in it.  So, on a hunch, I changed the code to look like this:

```
var bulkData = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity);
```

And it worked fine!  So, my question is, why is it that when I create the SQL Connection with a connection string that has a password in it, the password isn't included in the resulting SQL Connection's `ConnectionString` property?

Comment: I'm sure it is a security issue -- having the password in memory could be a security hole..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you include `Persist Security Info = True` in the connection string, `SqlConnection` will strip the password for security reasons.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the timer is up.